# ffmpeg -hls_time option not working correctly when running as a service

Tags: ffmpeg

I am running a ffmpeg command as a systemd service to catch a live RTSP stream and generate hls chunks, the chunks are set to be 30 seconds long with the -hls_time option, when I run the command on the console myself it works ok, but when it runs from the service chunks, wish are supposed to be 30 seconds long are 7 or 8 seconds.
This is the command:

> /usr/bin/ffmpeg -rtsp_flags prefer_tcp -i
>   "rtsp://192.168.1.16:554/user=admin&password=&channel=1&stream=1.sdp"
>   -acodec copy -vcodec copy -hls_time 30 -hls_list_size 10 -hls_flags append_list+delete_segments -f hls -use_localtime 1
>   -hls_segment_filename "/home/zurikato/video-backup/${FILENAME_FORMAT}_hls.ts"
>   /home/zurikato/video-backup/playlist.m3u8

I'm a beginner in ffmpeg and linux services, so please indulge me if it is a simple matter.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When using vcodec copy, you are at the mercy of the key frame  interval of the incoming media. Nothing you can do server side unless you transcode the video stream.

Comment: But why does it works wrong only when it is run as a service? And if it was that, do you have any solution?